# Why this is Kronecker-delta?

Tags: tensor-products, parsevals-identity

I was trying to prove this theorem: If $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{in\pi x/L}$, then show that $\langle|f(x)|^2\rangle = \sum |c_n|$

I checked the solution:

$\langle|f(x)|^2\rangle = \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L}(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{in\pi x/L})(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{c_n}e^{-in\pi x/L})dx$

then change the second index $n \to m$, and eventually get:

$$\langle|f(x)|^2\rangle = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \bar{c_m}\int_{-L}^{L}e^{i(n-m)\pi x/L} dx$$

then we have:$$\int_{-L}^{L} e^{i(n-m)\pi x/L} dx = 2L\delta_{nm} = \frac{2\sin\pi(n-m)}{(n-m)\pi /L}$$

why this is a kronecker-delta tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly in the definition of $\delta_{nm}$. What happens if $n = m$? If $n \ne m$?

Comment: I am thinking about why sin\pi(n-m)/[(n-m)\pi] = 1 when n = m, because it seems that the term is undefined

Comment: Don't use the formula--just evaluate the integral there. What happens?

Comment: awwwww, thank you!